# How to sync Ctrl+mousewheel across controls?

Tags: wpf

I have a class which handles a scrollbar PreviewMouseWheel event which zooms a timeline control, and everything works perfectly, except that I have to be over the scrollbar for the clr+mouse zoom to visually change the state of the scrollbar thumb. I have implemented the same PreviewMouseWheel event in the timeline control which has a different class for its datacontext, which zooms, but does not visually update the adjacent scrollbar control. What would be the best approach to handle the clr+mouse across the entire window?

```
        public void ZoomScrollbar_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {        
        FrameworkElement el;
        el = (FrameworkElement)sender;

        if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
        {
            var newValue = InitialZoomValue;
            if(e.Delta > 0)
            {
                newValue += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                newValue -= 1;
            }

            OnZoomScroll(newValue);
            InitialZoomValue = newValue;
        }
    }

            <Style x:Key="TimelineToolboxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type controls:TimelineToolbox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:TimelineToolbox}">
                        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ScrollBar x:Name="ZoomScrollbar"
                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                       Minimum="1"
                                       Maximum="12"
                                       Value="{TemplateBinding InitialZoomValue}"
                                       SmallChange="1"                                           
                                       Style="{DynamicResource ZoomScrollBarStyle}"
                                       BorderThickness="9,0" 
                                       Width="22" 
                                       Margin="0" 
                                       BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                                       Background="Black"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Any ideas at all?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the mouse wheel to sync with the scrollbar by calling the scrollbar's PreviewMouseWheel event handler from code behind.

```
        private void TimelineBand_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
        {
            TimeLineToolBoxControl.ZoomScrollbar_PreviewMouseWheel(sender, e);
        }
    }
```